# sticky header on scrolling a div with hidden overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I've been desperately trying to find a pure javascript solution that would allow scrolling of the content of a div (a fixed height div, with overflow: scroll)..

I've seen plenty of jquery examples, with window.scroll, but I've really been struggling to get this to work on the div element as pure css.

Any example similar to what i'm trying to do is,

```
$('div.scrollingDiv').scroll(function () {
var active = null;
$('.scrollingDiv h4').each(function (idx, val) {
    var topOffset = $(val).offset().top;
    if (topOffset < 20) // elem is 20 px from top
    {
        // Element nearest the top
        active = $(val);
    }

    $('.stickyTop').html("Funky Menu : " + active.text());
});
});
```

..but obviously without jquery :)

Help really appreciated...!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax translation of you JQuery based code to plain Javascript would be:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(e) { 
  document.querySelector('.scrollingDiv').onscroll = function(ev) {
    var title = "Funky Menu: ";
    var titleElem = document.querySelector('.stickyTop');
    var h4 = this.querySelectorAll('h4');
    var active = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < h4.length; i++) {
      if (h4[i].offsetTop - this.scrollTop < 30) {
        active = h4[i];
      } // elem is visible and close to top
    }
    if (active) {
      title += active.innerHTML;
    }
    titleElem.innerHTML = title;
  };
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Javier, that's a great help, but it doesnt seem to update the innerHTML of the .stickyTop element correctly -  https://plnkr.co/edit/gxkGqDgvrPc3T202biIS?p=preview

Comment: The translation was correct. However the original logic was not enough to achieve what you wanted. If I understood it correctly, you want to update the title as per the title of the visible paragraph. Try this new updated answer (following your fiddle).

Comment: Hi Javier, that's perfect! Thanks so much !!

Comment: You're very welcome. Will you mark as the right answer? If you can.

Comment: Sure, Unfortunately, i see the message 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15  reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.' However your help has been really appreciated and tottally worthy of an upvote !